# Now when we get a string from the user using gets(), where does the '\0' terminating character go?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

[image: Text from book]

[image: Code written in CodeBlocks]

Now when we declare a string, the last character is the null character, right.

(**Now pls see the image of the code and its output that i have attached**)

As you can see in the image attached, i am getting the null character at the 7th posn!!! What is happening?

According to the book i refer to(**see the other image attached**), a string always has an extra character associated with it, at the end of the string, called the null character which adds to the size of the string.
But by the above code i am getting the null character at the 7th position, although according to the book, i should get it at the 6th position.
Can someone explain the output pls?

Any help is really appreciated!!

Thank You!

Comment: Your program performs a buffer overrun (when the user's input is sufficiently long), and therefore exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Do _not_ post pictures to code and/or actually any other text. Instead, post the corresponding text inline, quoting approriately as a reference in case you are not the copyright owner.

Comment: Igor Tandetnik and  Dietmar Kühl, Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do *not* use `gets()` - ever! It is entirely immaterial what `gets()` does as is has *no* place in any reasonably written code! It is certainly removed from the C++ standard and, as far as I know, also from C (I think C removed it first). `gets()` happily overruns the buffer provided as it doesn't even know the size of the storage provided. It was blamed as the primary reason for most hacks of systems.

In the code you linked to there is such a buffer overrun. Also not that `sizeof()` determines the size of a variable. It does not consider its content in any shape or form: `sizeof(str)` will not change unless you change the type of `str`. If you want to determine the size of the string in that array you'll need to use `strlen(str)`.

If you really need to read a string into a C array using `FILE*` functions, you shall use `fgets()` which, in addition ot the pointer to the storage and the stream (e.g. `stdin` for the default input stream) also takes the size of the array as parameter.  `fgets()` fails if it can't read a complete null-terminated string.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a `char` array that can hold up to 5 `char`s, however, `dummy\0` is 6 characters long, resulting in buffer overflow.